# change background color on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the background color of button "game-add" when the button is clicked. And when "X" is clicked in overlay, I want to change it back into previous color. This is my code

```js
$('.game-add').click(function() {
   $(".game-add").css("background-color","5da93c");
  $('#overlay').toggleClass('active');
 // calcs bottom of button 
  var bottom = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight(true);
  $('#overlay').css({
    'top': bottom + 'px',
  });
});

$('#close').click(function(){
     $(".game-add").css("background-color","1D1D1D");
  $('#overlay').removeClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link game-add">ADD GAME</button>
<div id="overlay">
    <a href="#" id="close" class="pull-right" style="color: #fff;">X</a>
    <h2>This is an overlay</h2>
</div>
```

Any help will be largely appreciated. Thank You

Comment: Can you tell us what the current problem is?

Comment: does not change color at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `#` hash/numbersign, so the color isn't recognized.

```
 // Code above
 $('.game-add').click(function() {
  $(this).css("background-color","#5da93c");
  $('#overlay').toggleClass('active');
 // The rest of the code
```

Comment: #=hash £=pound. Sorry you've been educated wrong in the past.

Comment: @Jamiec # is also known as the pound sign or the number sign in American English, used to prefix weights or numbers, 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign

Comment: Yes I know. It was a slightly tongue in cheeck comment that Americans are educated incorrectly about the difference between a hash and a pound. Didnt mean any offense :) +1 for the correct answer.

Comment: I just couldn't find the right word for #, so I googled it. But I've changed it to hash/numbersign, sounds a lot better

Answer (score 2):

Here Try this add class and remove class method in jquery

Fisrt of All create A class With Background-color

```
<style>
    .btncolor{
        background-color:red;
    }
</style>
```

Then Just Some Minor Changes in Your Script

```
        <script>
$('.game-add').click(function() {
       $(this).addClass("btncolor"); // here 'btncolor' Class Will be added On click 
      $('#overlay').toggleClass('active');
     // calcs bottom of button 
      var bottom = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight(true);
      $('#overlay').css({
        'top': bottom + 'px',
      });
    });

    $('#close').click(function(){
         $(".game-add").removeClass("btncolor"); //Here Class Will be removed on  click from Button
      $('#overlay').removeClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting the `#` before for hex values. After changing these lines

```
$(".game-add").css("background-color","5da93c");
$(".game-add").css("background-color","1D1D1D");
```

to

```
$(".game-add").css("background-color","#5da93c");
$(".game-add").css("background-color","#1D1D1D");
```

gives me a result where colors are changed when clicking on the `button` and `a`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer you can just use `this` in place of repeating the slector `.game-add` - but that is not the fix to the issue.

You've forgotten the `#` symbol which preceeds a hex color in css.

```js
$('.game-add').click(function() {
   $(this).css("background-color","#5da93c");
  $('#overlay').toggleClass('active');
 // calcs bottom of button 
  var bottom = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight(true);
  $('#overlay').css({
    'top': bottom + 'px',
  });
});

$('#close').click(function(){
     $(".game-add").css("background-color","#1D1D1D");
  $('#overlay').removeClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link game-add">ADD GAME</button>
<div id="overlay">
    <a href="#" id="close" class="pull-right" style="color: #fff;">X</a>
    <h2>This is an overlay</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Added some changes

```
 $("#close").css("background-color","#d1a0a0"); 
 // needed the `#` infront of color
```

and

```
 $('.game-add').click(function(){
```

to

```
$('.game-add').click(function(){
```

```js
$('.game-add').click(function() {
   $(".game-add").css("background-color","5da93c");
  $('#overlay').toggleClass('active');
 // calcs bottom of button 
  var bottom = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight(true);
  $('#overlay').css({
    'top': bottom + 'px',
  });
});

$('.game-add').click(function(){
     $(".game-add").css("background-color","#d1a0a0");
  $('#overlay').removeClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link game-add">ADD GAME</button>
<div id="overlay">
    <a href="#" id="close" class="pull-right" style="color: #fff;">X</a>
    <h2>This is an overlay</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not have checked your console there is an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

To get rid of this error just include the jquery library path in the head and you're good to go. For example `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`. I did test with this and it worked!